# Editing Rejections and Penalty Time

Tags: discussion, support, editing

How many times can your edits on another persons question be rejected before it's disabled?
How long is the penalty?

Comment: This sort of question is usually best asked in [meta.se] - and it surely has been asked there already, have a good look before you post there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days),

> When deciding on whether we should ban or not, we now look at your last **7 days** of activity.
>
> If `(rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5`, you will be auto-banned.

[This thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected) puts the penalty at seven days of edit banning.

Both posts are fairly old, though [this newer thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173604/losing-the-ability-to-suggest-edits) confirms them. The exact details might have changed slightly. This is **not** to say that you should go and experimentally figure out where the boundaries currently sit.

For more, see the [edit-ban tag on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edit-ban?page=2&sort=votes&pagesize=15).